# Как реализовать локализацию без Update и перезагрузки игры в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, локализация

Сделал так, но из-за Update теряется производительность...

```
    public GameObject rusIMG, engIMG;
    public string ru, en;
    Text text;

    void Start () {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("lang") == "en") {
            engIMG.SetActive (false);
            rusIMG.SetActive (true);
        }
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("lang") == "ru") {
            rusIMG.SetActive (false);
            engIMG.SetActive (true);
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        if (rusIMG.activeSelf) {
            if (ru != "") {
                text.text = ru;
            }
        } 
        if (engIMG.activeSelf) {
            if (en != "") {
                text.text = en;
            }
        }
    }

  void OnMouseDown()
    {
        switch (gameObject.name)
        {
            case "eng":
                PlayerPrefs.SetString ("lang" , "en");
                engIMG.SetActive (false);
                rusIMG.SetActive (true);
            break;

            case "rus":
                PlayerPrefs.SetString ("lang" , "ru");
                rusIMG.SetActive (false);
                engIMG.SetActive (true);
            break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Google: Unity3D Event System

Comment: @Yaroslav , пробовал, язык не меняется при использовании методов.

Comment: Реализация не верная. Выложи.

Comment: @Yaroslav , может реализация и верная, просто не совсем понимаю когда и как вызывать метод, ведь нужно чтобы функция работала без перезагрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Наконец оказался у компа

```
using UnityEngine.Events;

public enum kLengvich { English, Russian }

[System.Serializable]
public class LengvichEvent : UnityEvent<kLengvich> { }

public class Lengvich : MonoBehaviour {
    public kLengvich CurrentLengvich;
    public LengvichEvent LengvichChange;

    private void Awake() {
        LengvichChange = new LengvichEvent();
        MyConstance.Lengvich = this; // Даем ссылку в статический класс, что бы не заморачиваться с сылками
    }

    public void Set (kLengvich lengvich) { // <-- Меняет язык
        CurrentLengvich = lengvich;
        LengvichChange.Invoke(CurrentLengvich);
    }
}

public static class MyConstance {
    public static Lengvich Lengvich;
}
// .....
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LengvichText : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private string _textRu;
    [SerializeField] private string _textEn;
    private Text _text;

    private void Awake () {
        _text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        if (MyConstance.Lengvich != null) { // Обращаемся через статический класс
            MyConstance.Lengvich.LengvichChange.AddListener(ChangeLengvich);
            ChangeLengvich(MyConstance.Lengvich.CurrentLengvich);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeLengvich (kLengvich lengvich) {
        switch (lengvich) {
            case kLengvich.English: _text.text = _textEn; break;
            case kLengvich.Russian: _text.text = _textRu; break;
        }
    }
}
// .....
MyConstance.Lengvich.Set(kLengvich.English); // <-- Установили английский
```

Или еще проще, без `UnityEvent` через `Singleton`.

```
public enum kLengvich { English, Russian }
public delegate void LengvichDelegate (kLengvich lengvich);

public class Lengvich {
    private static Lengvich instance;

    public static Lengvich getInstance () {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Lengvich();
        return instance;
    }

    public kLengvich CurrentLengvich { get; private set; }
    private List<LengvichDelegate> _delegates;

    private Lengvich () {
        _delegates = new List<LengvichDelegate>();
    }

    public void Set (kLengvich lengvich) {
        CurrentLengvich = lengvich;
        if (_delegates != null)
            foreach (LengvichDelegate ld in _delegates)
                if (ld != null)
                    ld(CurrentLengvich);
    }

    public void AddListener (LengvichDelegate changeLengvich) {
        if (_delegates != null)
            _delegates.Add(changeLengvich);
    }

    public void RemoveListener (LengvichDelegate changeLengvich) {
        if (_delegates != null)
            _delegates.Remove(changeLengvich);
    }
}
// .....
public class LengvichText : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Awake () {
        Lengvich.getInstance().AddListener(ChangeLengvich);
    }

    private void OnDestroy () {
        Lengvich.getInstance().RemoveListener(ChangeLengvich);
    }

    private void ChangeLengvich (kLengvich lengvich) {

    }
}
// .....
Lengvich.getInstance().Set(kLengvich.English);
```